# How can I inflate a static array resource in Android the Scala way?

Tags: android, scala

I wonder what's the scala way to access an array as a `TypedResources`...

I tried the following:

```
class PersonActivity extends AppCompatActivity with TypedFindView {

  implicit val context = this

  lazy val persons = TR.array.persons
  // lazy val persons = TR.array.persons.value
  lazy val personSearchEngine = new PersonSearchEngine(persons) // expects a Seq[String]
  // lazy val personSearchEngine = new PersonSearchEngine(getResources.getStringArray(TR.array.persons.resid)
  ...
}
```

The last line that is uncommented forces me to implement `findViewById[V <: View](id: Int)`. What's the scala way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I was missing was an import to bring the implicit conversions into scope:

```
import TypedResource._
```

Then you can use your static resource like this:

```
// allows accessing `.value` on TR.resource.constants
implicit val context = this

lazy val personSearchEngine = new PersonSearchEngine(TR.array.persons.value)
```